# How to mark method by annotation @ModelAttribute that this method invokes before loading concrete view

Tags: java, spring

How do I mark a method with the `@ModelAttribute` annotation so that this method is invoked before loading the concrete view in spring?

Comment: What did you try so far? Could you share some more details?

Comment: I was needs by object in 3-4 methods, but at this controller many methods and every request loads object in request.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method like this to your controller:

```
@ModelAttribute("myString")
public String getMyString() { 
    return "my string";
}
```

Is then accessible in the JSP as a variable named "myString"

Comment: At this way this methode will invoke on every invoke any of controller's method. I want invoke this method only before my view

Comment: I dont follow. Do you mean you want this to execute after your controller method but before your view?